# jQuery form validation logic

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, logic

I have the following code:

```
function showError(l, msg) {
  $('#'+l).css({'color':'red'});
  $('#error').html(msg).fadeIn(500);
}

$(document).ready(function(){

$('#form').submit(function() {
  if($('#username').val() == '') {
    showError('labelUser', 'Please enter a username');
    return false;
  }
  if($('input[type=password]')[0].value != $('input[type=password]')[1].value) {
    showError('labelPassword', 'Password does not match');
    return false;
  }
  // etc...
  $('label').css({'color':'black'});
  $('#error').html('').fadeOut(200);
  return true;
});

});
```

I have in my form a total of 10 fields (name, first name, email etc...). As you can see in my script (`//etc...`), I repeat the SAME case over and over if a field is valid or not.

I think repeating the `showError` and `return false` is not a good solution.

Is there an easier way (or better) to use validate data? Thank you

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use the jQuery Validation plugin? It makes this type of thing super easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the jQuery Validation Plugin.

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

It does this type of thing without writing any code.